# undefined reference to `sperm'

Tags: c, gcc

I have gcc-4.6.0 installed and I'm doing everything on this instruction: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html
I hooked up all the includes and wrote in the code:

```
printf("%10.10s\n", sperm (statbuf.st_mode));
```

And at compilation there were here such errors:

```
 ls.c: In function 'main':
 ls.c:37:25: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
 ls.c:68:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sperm' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 ./ccmPDCcZ.o: In function `main':
 ls.c:(.text+0x238): undefined reference to `sperm'
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <langinfo.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main()
{
  DIR *dir = opendir(".");
  if(dir)
  {
    struct dirent *ent;
    while((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
      if (stat(ent->d_name, &statbuf) == -1) //получаем инфу
        continue;
      if( (pwd=getpwuid(statbuf.st_uid)) != NULL)
      {
        printf("%-8.8s", pwd->pw_name);
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening directory\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh .....s-perm.

Comment: Please reformat this question for easier reading and provide maybe a minimalistic working code snippet.

Comment: ls.c: In function 'main':
ls.c:37:25: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
ls.c:68:29: error: 's' undeclared (first use in this function)
ls.c:68:29: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
ls.c:68:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'perm' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Comment: Post the code rather then an external link - the page may be modified or removed rendering this question less than useful.

Comment: My bet is that you failed to declare `sperm` before line `68` in `ls.c`. Please post [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I wrote the source, try to compile

Comment: That code doesn't even contain `sperm`.

Comment: And where to get it?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't match the error messages. Please post real code and real error messages.

Comment: An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9639381) to a related question contains a possible implementation of `sperm`.

Comment: Interesting that the POSIX spec has that undefined function in an example.  See [this Yahoo question](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091108232812AA2Vtb4) or this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9638714/12711) for some possible implementations..

Comment: @Coldspeed same, I also tried to look it up with `man sperm` :|

Answer (score 2):

In the context of thecode in question:

```
/* Print out type, permissions, and number of links. */
printf("%10.10s", sperm (statbuf.st_mode));
printf("%4d", statbuf.st_nlink);
```

It appears to be a function to print file permissions as a string.  In which case you can use the method described at [How do I print file permissions as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26616038/how-do-i-print-file-permissions-as-a-string).

Comment: Is there a ready function or should I write?

Comment: `strmode` in Linux (I assume that's where you are) would pretty much do what you want. Just slice off what you don't need from the result string.